# Odd Control behavior Visual Basic Windows Form

Tags: vb.net

I've dynamically added a text box to my main form on a button press:

```
Public Widget As UUTWidgetPanel 
...
 Public Sub New(ByVal UnitNo As Integer)
    Me.UnitNo = UnitNo

    Widget = New UUTWidgetPanel(UnitNo)
End Sub
...
Public Class UUTWidgetPanel
     Public ContainerWidget As New FlowLayoutPanel
     Public UnitLabel as New Label
     Public CurrDrawTB As New TextBox

     Public Sub New(ByVal UnitNo As Integer)

       With UnitLabel
        .Text = "Unit " & UnitNo.ToString
        .Height = 25
        .Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top + AnchorStyles.Left
        .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    End With

     With CurrDrawTB
        .Width = 123
        .Height = 25
        .Text = "some text"
        .ReadOnly = False
        .Visible = True
        .ForeColor = Color.Blue
        '.Text = "CurrDrawTB"
    End With

  With ContainerWidget
     .Controls.Add(UnitLabel)
     .Controls.Add(CurrDrawTB)
```

I add the "ContainerWidget" FlowLayoutPanel to my main form from a method called by a button click as follows:

```
 Private Sub AddUUT()   'adds instance of TestUnit to TestUnits, then it's controls to main form's "FlowLayoutPanel1"
    Dim highestArrIdx As Integer = TestUnits.Count
    TestUnits.Add(New TestUnit(highestArrIdx + 1))
  FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(TestUnits.Item(highestArrIdx).Widget.ContainerWidget)
End Sub
```

Oddly enough, when I try to retrieve the info from `CurrDrawTB`, I receive an empty string, rather than the value `"some text"`:

```
  Dim text As String
  text = Me.Widget.CurrDrawTB.Text
```

But writing to the textbox works:

```
  Me.Widget.CurrDrawTB.Text = "Hi!"    <--I see "Hi!" in the debugger and on the form.
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The constructor definition for your widget shown above does not match your call... is there something missing?

Comment: @vbnet3d oops, updated. Thanks!

Comment: it still doesnt match

Comment: @Plutonix sorry, I think it's cleaned up now.

Comment: The way `CurrDrawTB` is declared (with NEW), it will always return something even if it isnt created.  Create the instance in the UUTWidgetPanel constructor.   It may behave differently and allow you to work out what is wrong (hard to tell without usage code)

Comment: What happens after the "ContainerWidget" With Block? I just did a test on my own, and it is working fine with what you are showing. I would suggest that it is being overwritten at some point further down than what you have shown here.

Comment: @vbnet3d nothing, actually. The "Widget"  `ContainerWidget` gets added to the main form from a button press on the main form:  `TestUnits.Add(New TestUnit(highestArrIdx + 1))
 FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(TestUnits.Item(highestArrIdx).Widget.ContainerWidget)`

Comment: I can see the text value and update from debugging on the main form (looking at the array the class containing ContainerWidget sits in.

Comment: @Rachael Where is ContainerWidget defined?

Comment: @vbnet3d See edits under declaration of UUTWidgetPanel. I forgot to include that in attempts to simplify code. Oddly, the UnitLabel text is always available to me. It's specifically the TextBoxes that I am unable to retrieve text from, even with `ReadOnly = False`

Comment: @MicroVirus I was using that to ensure (upon first test) that the textbox I was seeing was in fact CurrDrawTB.

Comment: Conducted an experiment: switched CurrDrawTB to Label and was able to retrieve text perfectly with no errors. Switched back in the declaration to TextBox and retrieved nothing once again. I'm really baffled here.

Comment: @Rachael are you using a custom TextBox control, or the standard control?

Comment: I thought maybe the textbox wasn't large enough to contain the text and that wordwrap was an issue, but if I test out what `123 x 25` is it should be more than large enough, unless you are using a very large font?

Comment: @vbnet3d just standard. I've added controls in this manner before (granted I am not doing something incorrectly and different without noticing)

Comment: @Rachael I have tested everything that you have here, and it all works for me. When you add the controls to the ContainerWidget, I believe that they are actually created as copies, and are not handles back to the original control. This means that you could manipulate one or the other without data passing between them. Can you provide a little more context for how this data is being retrieved?

Comment: @vbnet3d thanks a lot. I added my method for getting a new instance of the ContainerWidget control (holding the problematic TextBox) to the question. See "AddUUT()" section. Otherwise there really isn't more. Thanks for all your help. I may have to just keep combing.

Comment: Run through the creation part with a debugger and see if everything goes as planned.

Comment: Everyone, this is embarrassing. Thanks everyone for help. @vbnet3d you are right. Please post an answer so I can at least give you a point. I had written a function "ClearTestUnitData()" I didn't realize was running. I don't know how the label version of CurrDrawTB escaped being wiped. I'm really sorry for all that--I just need sleep. You've helped a lot.

Comment: @Rachael I thought that might be the case - don't feel bad, it is a really common mistake. I've done it, I don't know how many times.

Comment: @vbnet3d thanks so much, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CurrDrawTB Text property is being overwritten. This is a very common issue. The logic that you have posted works fine apart from this.